# AS3 setInterval Animation Choppy

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

The following animation strategy is turning out very choppy in AS3 while manipulating shapes.

```
setInterval(function():void {
    shape.x += 3;
},15);
```

I'm new to Flash and I understand there are different animation mechanisms built into the language that I can easily learn, but I'm just wondering why this particular strategy is animating so poorly.

I have used the exact same technique to smoothly animate HTML elements with JavaScript on the exact same machine.  Do AS3 and JS handle setInterval loops fundamentally differently, causing one to be more efficient than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actionscript/Flex executes on frames. Only so many things can be done on a frame. The applications get slow and choppy when the number of instructions to execute exceed the "time available" for the frame - this prevents UI updating because other instructions in the frame are still running. Also, this type of action is expensive - objects need to be allocated every 15ms (memory allocation is expensive + garbage collector cost), you should use the Timer object instead.

Alternatively, you can listen on the topLevelApplication for enter frame and exit frame events to create a clever event loop, but things like GreenThreads already do this well.

Also, setInterval is a browser implemetation in JavaScript (it is not part of the JavaScript language, all browsers implement it though). Flex uses a variant of the Timer object for setInterval.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the informative response!  So the largest issue with setInterval is the reallocation of memory with each successive function call?  I'll look into both of your suggestions, probably starting with the event-based system because that seems to be more in the spirit of AS3 and much more maintainable for game animation if organized well.